# Node fs error: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, fs

I test it with the postman,
I am facing this error and I can't solve it.

Error:

node:internal/fs/utils:671
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined

My Code:

```
const Blog = require("../models/blog");
const Category = require("../models/category");
const Tag = require("../models/tag");
const User = require("../models/user");
const formidable = require("formidable");
const slugify = require("slugify");
import { stripHtml } from "string-strip-html";
const _ = require("lodash");
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler");
const fs = require("fs");

exports.create = (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
     if (err) {
       return res.status(400).json({
         error: err,
       });
     }

     const { title, body, categories, tags } = fields;

     let blog = new Blog();
     blog.title = title;
     blog.body = body;
     blog.slug = slugify(title).toLowerCase();
     blog.mtitle = `${title} | ${process.env.APP_NAME}`;
     blog.mdesc = stripHtml(body.substring(0, 160)).result;
     blog.postedBy = req.auth._id;

     if (files.photo) {
       if (files.photo.size > 10000000) {
         return res.status(400).json({
           error: "Image should be less than 1mb in size",
         });
       }
       blog.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
       blog.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
     }

     blog.save((err, result) => {
       if (err) {
         return res.status(400).json({
           error: err,
         });
       }
       res.json(result);
     });
   });
 };
```

Comment: You're using one `fs` function (`fs.readFileSync()`) and the error is telling you you're passing it an undefined path argument. In other words, `files.photo.path` is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `files.photo.filepath`  instead of `files.photo.path`

You can check "File usage" in Formidable documentation here
https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable#file

Answer (score 0):

It absolutely worked for me.

```
product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.filepath);
        product.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
```